# How to verify and get well known ssl certificates?

Tags: firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate

I just delete all SSL certificates and certificate authorities from mozilla firefox. Now its not even let me open the gmail.com.

How can I selectively get and verify gmail certifcate online (and any other certificate)? (without reinstalling firefox).

Comment: Why not re-install Firefox? It's small and doubtless way faster than trying to piece together a broken installation.

Comment: there are many quick and easy ways. I just want to find out is there a central repository where we can get and verify well known certificates.

Comment: I found the half-answer, [link](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) can be used to verify well known site's certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the full list back from Mozilla:

https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu provides a `ca-certificates` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ca-certificates) and [Debian provides a similar `ca-certificates` package](http://packages.debian.org/sid/ca-certificates). If you wish to inspect both of these and select the certificates you trust you can include them on your system manually. While neither Ubuntu nor Debian can vouch for the certificate authorities included in the package, millions of people rely on them for daily use. If you're on a Debian or Ubuntu system, simply type `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates`. If you're not on Debian or Ubuntu, then you'll probably want to download the `.tar.gz` source files from either of the linked webpages above.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be the case that you delete your certificate and you will not be able to open your gmail.

When you will visit gmail again the server will send you the certificate.
You just need to save them, and it should work.You may also try using https:gmail.com/.
I think you have disabled you cookies functionality in you browser.

Comment: I have not deleted google's certificate, I deleted the list of CAs.